# The message wasn't mapped in Eclipse Vorto Semantic Normalizer middleware

Tags: mosquitto, eclipse-vorto

I'm flowing [this link](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/development/docs/tutorials/create_mapping_pipeline.md), all is OK before step 3.4. But when I use this `mosquitto_pub` command to publish the message to the Bosch IOT hub.

```
mosquitto_pub -h mqtt.bosch-iot-hub.com -p 8883 -u 4712@t65a6a75c6b4f429981ba16d1b3d5f414 -P secret -t telemetry/t65a6a75c6b4f429981ba16d1b3d5f414/4712 -m '"103.3223","3.2322"' --cafile iothub.crt
```

[image: The Normalizer Frontend shows the message I published.]

But the output log didn't have any message like the [tutorial](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/development/docs/tutorials/create_mapping_pipeline.md)

[image: and none error message.]

[image: The mapping_specs have added.]

[image: And all the plugins are inactive.]

Why? What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not started the normaliser middleware with any outbound handler plugin. So in your case, in order to send any incoming telemetry data to an AMQP topic, you need to start the middleware with the [AMQP plugin](https://github.com/eclipse/vorto-examples/tree/master/vorto-middleware/middleware-ext-amqp/Readme.md)

Once done so, you should be able to see the logs in the middleware dashboard, under monitoring, appearing as outbound messages.

Sorry for the confusion, I have changed the tutorial in order to make it clearer, see https://github.com/eclipse/vorto/blob/master/docs/tutorials/create_mapping_pipeline.md#4-setting-up-eclipse-vorto-payload-normalization-middleware-with-vorto-amqp-plugin